# Correct return type of count() from <algorithm>

Tags: c++, algorithm, auto

*Warning, this is picky!*
Most people store the result of *count()* from *algorithm* in some kind of **signed integer** i.e. long* type or *ptr_diff* from *cstddef*:

```
vector<int> vec = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1,};
long result = count(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), 1); // result == 3
```

A modern and lazy approach:

```
auto result = count(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), 1);
```

Both are fine. The first one could become a problem, if the underlying primitive types changes. The second one gurantess the correct type, but the type is not known (by the programmer). In a typed language the programmer should known the involved library types, not necessarily the involved primitive types. Imagine an algorithm which returns an *unsigned* and later the program uses the *unsigned* accidentally with *signed* variables. A look on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) shows for C++11:

```
template< class InputIt, class T >
typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type
    count( InputIt first, InputIt last, const T &value );
```

I think the definition of the returned type is:

```
iterator_traits<vector<int>::const_iterator>::difference_type result = count(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), 1);
```

I don't claim that this is a best practice! I just want to know the type, but not use that definition in practice. The *difference_type* of vector seems to be also a choice, the *count* function is not from the container, but from it's iterator. Is my definition of the variable *result* correct?
Thanks

PS: The underlying type used by GCC 7.2 on X86_64 GNU/Linux is really *long*, at least *typeid* told me so.

Comment: Here's a trick: If you want to find out the type of something, wrap it in a decltype and create an instance of an undefined template struct: `template<class> struct show_me; show_me</*...*/>{};` More reliable than `typeid`.

Comment: Yes, that is the type for that iterator. But it seems like really, your question is not 'what is the type', but rather a philosophical musing on whether that *should* be the type? `difference_type` must be large enough to store the size, since it must be large enough to represent `end - begin`, which *is* the size.

Comment: @underscore_d; I want to know the full type declaration, that's why I warn about being picky.

Comment: You could also argue that it shouldn't matter what the actual type is. If it matters you can then `decltype`, for example to get its `std::numeric_limits`. There are people on both sides of this debate.

Comment: @Peter Then you already worked it out by looking at the standard declaration and substituting the appropriate iterator.

Comment: @Jarod42: Correct! Fixed that.

Comment: @underscore_d: Make an answer :)

Comment: @Rakete1111: Can you elaborate that a little bit? Or provide a link? Thanks

Comment: @Peter https://godbolt.org/g/NyEohx

Comment: @Rakete1111: That's funny! The compiler error message shows the underlying primitive type. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

indeed, in

```
auto result = count(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), 1);
```

`auto` is `std::iterator_traits<std::vector<int>::const_iterator>::difference_type`.

Comment: I have voted for both answers (both correct) and picked this one as solution, because I'm more interested in definition.

Answer (score 3):

The [std::count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) is of `std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type` type which is of [std::ptrdiff_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t) type which is an implementation defined `typedef` for a **signed integer** type. So ultimately it's implementation defined. The possible implementation gives a clue:

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type  // <--
    count(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value)
{
    typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type ret = 0;
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*first == value) {
            ret++;
        }
    }
    return ret; // <--
}
```